# How to deal with multiple select tags with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I got such problem:

I need to configure all options on the page with Selenium.
I need to use Select class from Python Selenium.
Here is example:

```
select = (Select(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('select'))
select.select_by_index(2)
```

and I got nothing instead!
I think that Select works only with one element. And what to do, when i need to configure ALL select in this way?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the relevant HTML code containing `select` tag? Thanks.

Comment: When you say `Select class`, do you mean a CSS class (as opposed to the `select` html element)? If its css, then you need to add a `.` prefix, i.e. `find_elements_by_css_selector('.select')`

Comment: It can be any SELECT tag!
And i need iterate through every of them!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generator for that; so you can iterate while wrapping the elements:

```py
selects = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('select')
def wrapped_selects():
    for element in selects:
        yield Select(element)
```

or you can wrap them all:

```py
selects = map(Select, driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('select'))
```